# Vertical scroll bar isn't working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, web-frontend

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="section">

    <div class="row container-fluid" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: red; top: 0; height: auto; overflow-y: auto; ">
            <ul>
                <li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li>
                <li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li>
                <li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li>
                <li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li>
                <li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li>
                <li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li>
                <li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li>
                <li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li>
                <li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10" style="background-color: green; top: 0; height: 400px; "></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
background-color: #F7F9F9 !important;

}

.navbar{
    background-color: #FDFEFE !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-header{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#section .row{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    display: block;
}

.col-md-2{
    overflow-y: auto;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  width:12px;
  _background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius:12px;
  border:4px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
  background-clip:content-box;
  _background-color:#bfbfbf;
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    border-radius:12px;
    border:4px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
    background-clip:content-box;
    background-color:#A0A0A0;}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background-color:#e6e6e6;}
```

I wanted to get the slim vertical scroll bar. Everyone seems to do the same thing but it's not working for me. FYI I have copied this from various other websites so I might be going wrong in some places. I hope someone will help me out.

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: hidden` is stopping anything beyond the viewport from being shown. Therefore you can't scroll below 100% because there is no below 100%.

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* Remove this */
}
```

Comment: i want to scroll left part by making the right part stationary. How will i be able to achieve that? if i were to remove `overflow:hidden` , all page will scroll.

Comment: seems like if i add the height of the left column, scroll bar works just fine. but it doesn't seem to work with height in auto.